# Aliasing a table with _

Tags: sql, database, oracle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBnSq.png)

Write SQL query to create a view FAMILY, containing `TENANT_SS, TENANT_NAME`, names of the family members `(NAME)`.  For those tenants that do not have family members listed in TENANT_FAMILY, display null. `[Use TENANT and TENANT_FAMILY tables]`

I still need to finish the whole question, but the first question is aliasing a table with _. As you know, I can do aliasing when a table name is a single word.`(ex.TENANT -> T.TENANT_SS)` Then, what do I need to do for a table with _? `(ex. Tenant_Family)`

```
CREATE VIEW FAMILY_VIEW
AS(SELECT T. TENANT_SS, T. TENANT_NAME, TF?.NAME
FROM TENANT T, TENANT_FAMILY TF?
```

Answer (score 0):

Alias names are made up. Use whatever name you like. TF would be a very good alias for a table called TENANT_FAMILY.

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!